# Ionic 2 Tabs Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

This error seems to be a plague haunting Ionic 2.  I've looked at several questions on this topic but none have been of help so far.

I've created this component Layout Component which wraps all my pages:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      {{pageName}}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ng-content>
</ng-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab [root]="usersPage" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="chat"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

and the TS File looks like so:

```
export class AstootLayoutComponent {

  @Input() pageName: string;

  usersPage: any = UsersPage;
  profilePage: any = ProfilePage;

}
```

Then I have a users page which consumes this component which looks like so:

```
<astoot-layout [pageName]="pageName">
  <ion-content padding>
    <page-list-base [detailPageType]="userDetailType" [baseProvider]="baseProvider" [config]="pageListConfiguration"></page-list-base>
  </ion-content>
</astoot-layout>
```

When I attempt to start my application I receive an error:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getList' of undefined
>       at PageListBaseComponent.set [as baseProvider] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115817:21)
>       at Wrapper_PageListBaseComponent.check_baseProvider (/AppModule/PageListBaseComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:38:31)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_UsersPage0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/UsersPage/component.ngfactory.js:80:35)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:111909:14)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:112104:44)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:111894:18)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_UsersPage_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/UsersPage/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:111909:14)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:112104:44)
>       at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:77367:20)
>       at NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:43575:40)
>       at NavControllerBase._transitionInit (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:43678:18)
>       at NavControllerBase._postViewInit (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:43531:14)
>       at NavControllerBase._viewTest (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:43627:25)
>       at NavControllerBase._nextTrns (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:43370:25)

Through some investigation the cause seems to be the fact that the AstootLayoutComponent references the Users page, where it resides in.  Some how the creates a forever loop.

Why is this happening, the documentation doesn't seem to mention that you can't next this component on the page.  How can I fix this?

**Bounty Edit**

I've created a [Repository](https://github.com/granthoff1107/Ionic-Sample-Max-Exceed) which replicates my issue

Just as a warning since the tabs controller is in a forever loop, and the api is pointed to github, so you may want to switch that before hitting there rate limit, you can change the url in the Environments.ts

Comment: I never see component tag inside other component tag before. Could you please provide some document about this?

Comment: This is common in angular.  The '<ng-content> </ng-content>' allows you to nest HTML components. I believe it's referred to as transclusion you can see a tutorial on it [here](https://www.google.com/amp/scotch.io/amp/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is really new for me.

Comment: What do you expect? You are loading nested components like `astoot-layout => users-page => astoot-layout => users-page => astoot-layout => users-page => astoot-layout => users-page => astoot-layout => users-page => astoot-layout => users-page =>  ....`

Comment: @yurzui according to ionic this is not expected behavior see this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12206#issuecomment-312349968).  That should only reference the page not nest the whole thing,

Comment: How would you use the tabs controller if the page you selected is not allowed to have the tabs controller on?

Comment: @johnny5 Are you using `Webpack/Gulp` and/or `Ionic CLI` ?

Comment: Ionic cli with webpack I believe

Comment: I don't know how it is related, Downgrading to `Typescript 2.3.0` seem to have solved the issue for some people. Alternatively, try running the app with `ionic build android --aot --minifycss --release` rather than `ionic cordova build android --prod`. Also, did you update your Ionic recently?

Comment: Thanks, I will test this when I get back home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add a Tabs Component.  Therefore some of the work you were doing in the astoot layout gets moved to this Tabs Component.  I opened a PR: https://github.com/granthoff1107/Ionic-Sample-Max-Exceed/pull/1

I tested this and no more stack errors since you no longer have the recursive relationship between the astoot layout and the ion-tabs.

Remove the tabs component from the Astoot Layout Component:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      {{pageName}}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ng-content>
</ng-content>
```

Create a seperate Tabs Component:

```
<ion-tabs>
   <ion-tab [root]="usersPage" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="chat"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="profilePage" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

With a type script file that contains the pages from the astoot layout component.

```
import { ProfilePage } from './../profile/profile';
import { UsersPage } from './../users/users';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

    usersPage: any = UsersPage;
    profilePage: any = ProfilePage;

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

Add your new tabs page the app.module.ts  and set your `rootPage: any = TabsPage;` this will now act as your master page and your content will be transcluded into your view.

Comment: I'm so glad you posted this.  This works amazing,  I  took the liberty of editing your answer to include everything because I'm closing that branch now it was for testing purposes

Comment: Awesome!  Please reward me the bounty.  Thanks!

Comment: I thought it did when I marked your answer as correct